# Live search through Array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have my array list name tableRows

```
 var tableRows = [
        [
            {
                'ColumnName': 'Checkbox'
            },
            {
                'ColumnName': 'TicketNumber',
                'Type': 'text',
                'Text': 20173100021
            },
            {
                'ColumnName': 'Type',
                'Type': 'text',
                'Text': 'Project'
            },
            {
                'ColumnName': 'Edits',
                'Type': 'text',
            },
            {
                'ColumnName': 'Name1',
                'Type': 'text',
                'CompanyName': 'CompanyA'
            },
            {
                'ColumnName': 'Name2',
                'Type': 'text',
                'CompanyName': 'CompanyB'
            }
        ]
    ];
```

how could I search CompanyName even my input is not exact for example I only typed "Comp", all CompanyName will display then if I typed "CompanyA", all with the same name will display in console.log. I used JavaScript by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.inlcudes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for this:

```js
var tableRows = [[{'ColumnName': 'Checkbox'},{'ColumnName': 'TicketNumber','Type': 'text','Text': 20173100021},{'ColumnName': 'Type','Type': 'text','Text': 'Project'},{'ColumnName': 'Edits','Type': 'text',},{'ColumnName': 'Name1','Type': 'text','CompanyName': 'CompanyA'},{'ColumnName': 'Name2','Type': 'text','CompanyName': 'CompanyB'}]];

console.log(tableRows[0].filter(item => item.CompanyName && item.CompanyName.toLowerCase().includes("coMP".toLowerCase())))

console.log(tableRows[0].filter(item => item.CompanyName && item.CompanyName.includes("A")))
```

There are also other methods like [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that can give you a lot of control over how and what is matched.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. But I have another question. What if my search value and CompanyName is not case sensitive?

For example, I typed "comp" I got no display

Comment: Hey @JohnJerickSorio, typically you would convert both to lowercase (or upper) with `toLowerCase` and then compare. I edited the first match to show this in the answer.